# Using declarativeContent API in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm following [this example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_url/background.js) to enable `pageAction` in a chrome extension:

```
// When the extension is installed or upgraded ...
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        // That fires when a page's URL contains a 'g' ...
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'g' },
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

I want to implement this in a production ready extension but I want to understand one thing: why this line `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener` is used? As I know the onInstalled will run only once after update or installation of the extension, so is possible to remove it and use only declarative content API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because declarativeContent rules are remembered internally.

Without chrome.runtime.onInstalled event you would register the rules each time the background script runs so for example a `"persistent":false` [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) can easily run 10, 100, or 1000 times a day. Re-registering many rules would be obviously wasteful and slow.

Comment: And what about this line `actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]` it will enable `pageAction` but also if the `pageAction.onClicked` listener is set, no popup is displayed if user click on the extension icon

Comment: Your current code enables the popup only on urls containing `g`.

Comment: This is the code from the example. In the code I'm working on I've changed the rule to `pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'www.myplay.com/video/*', schemes: ['https'] }` and visiting the page will only enable the icon, the `onClicked` event will not fire .

Comment: Your condition will never match because 1) `host` contains only the part before `/`, 2) `*` is not supported by the API. You can use `hostEquals: 'www.myplay.com', pathPrefix: '/video/'`